# Как переписать код, что бы пункт "Підписатися на розсилку" не отъезжал вправо при масштабировании экрана?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {  
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Futura PT", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* для корректного отображения текста на всех экранах*/
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /*для нормального скроллинга*/
}
.header-top {
   height:40px;
    background: #ffffff;
    line-height:40px;    
}    
nav {
  display:flex;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;  
}
nav .nav-title {
  color:#686868;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  margin-left: 68px; 
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
nav .navigation {
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  color: gray;
  flex-grow:1;
}
nav .navigation li {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px;
   /*странно, но нижняя тень работает только так, если поставить ; она будет отображаться некорректно*/   
   /*margin-bottom: 11px;
   margin-top: 25px;*/
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
         
}

nav .navigation li.selectable:hover {
box-shadow:0 -2px 0 0 #1c76bc inset;
}

nav .navigation li.left {
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
/* Подписаться на розсылку*/

nav .navigation a{
  color: #686868;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 19px;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>domjuristablog2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  <div class="header-top">
     Header top
  </div>
 </header>
      <nav>
     <div class="nav-title">Блог</div>
     <ul class="navigation">
       <li class="selectable"><a href="#">Для бізнесу</a></li>
       <li class="selectable"><a href="#">Для юристів</a></li>
       <li class="left"><a href="#">Підписатися на розсилку</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для nav .navigation{...} свойство

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Тогда у Вас всё, что не влезает на экран, будет перемещаться на следующую строку (в пределах flex'а, само собой). А дальше уже через @media(...){...} поправляйте стили под разные версии экранов, чтобы это смотрелось как-то по-человечески.

Answer (score 0):

Удалите свойство `flex-grow: 1`;

`nav .navigation li.left {
    flex-grow: 1;
...`

Comment: Сначало предлагаете удалить, а во второй строке - оставить и перенести на первое место. Это как?

Comment: @0xdb человек показал где удалить нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел более элегантное решение и поместил "Подписаться на расслыку" в отдельный див и задал ему координаты.